# android studio setting env variable PATH

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to change the environment variable `PATH` for building within Android Studio?

For command line builds, I set the `PATH` and run the gradle command. The build succeeds.

If I try to build from within android studio, the build fails, most likely because the build within Android Studio doesn't use the `PATH`